# SPUtility MakeReadOnly not working on Person fields in edit form

Tags: sharepoint-online, sputility

I'm customizing one of my edit forms with `sputility.js` to make some of my fields as readonly.

The readonly statement looks like this

```
SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('Title').MakeReadOnly();
```

It works perfectly fine for all fields except Person field. The Person field is not displaying any data after making it readonly. If i switch it back to editable field using `MakeEditable()` the value is still present.

How do i make the Person fields as readonly using SPutility.js v0.14.2
EDIT:

If i manually call the `MakeReadOnly()` from console it is working. I have written my code inside `document.ready()` function only. so it doesn't get called before the page loads.

I tried using `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push(Function)` , `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Function, "sp.js")` but they are also not helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put below code in **window.load()** and try.

```
var peopleField = SPUtility.GetSPField('People Picker Column Name');

peopleField.MakeReadOnly();
```

Reference Link : http://sputility.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=People%20fields

Comment: sorry, it is not working. :( still i'm getting blank fields. please see the edit to my question

Comment: Can you please call this in window.load() and try

Comment: it is working in `window.load()` thank you. I still see the edit form before it gets modified by the script. can i reduce that delay. ?

Comment: please modify your answer with window.load. i'll markit as accepted answer

Comment: Already done please check

Comment: You can hide "ms-formtable" in document.ready()  and then it will show in window.load(). It will help you