# SPUtility.GetSPField MakeReadOnly Not working on Required Person Field

Tags: 2016, read-only, sputility

On my edit form I have a required name field that I want to make readonly.

Here is what I have in javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    SPUtility.GetSPField("Name").MakeReadOnly();
    SPUtility.GetSPField("Date Created").MakeReadOnly();

});
```

When I do this, on page load I get this:

[image]

There is no name next to it.. but if I go into list settings and make the name field not required.. then it works as expected and I can see the name of the person in readonly mode.  Additionally, I don't have to do these steps for any other required field other than the person field.

Any work around to this?

Comment: What version of SharePoint you are working on?

Comment: @MarekSarad SharePoint 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a known problem with SPUtility.

Please see this answer:
[SPUtility MakeReadOnly not working on Person fields in edit form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/208904/sputility-makereadonly-not-working-on-person-fields-in-edit-form?rq=1)

Put below code in window.load() and try.

```
var peopleField = SPUtility.GetSPField('People Picker Column Name');

peopleField.MakeReadOnly();
```